# Search through multidimensional array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I got stuck trying to retrive array items. So here is the deal. I have a two dimentional array which has value and key so example of my data is:

```
[
    Object { css="SS", title="Apple"}, 
    Object { css="SS", title="Orange"}, 
    Object { css="SS", title="Banana"}
]
```

I want to see if an object exists in the array above. And I have no idea why its not working, here is my code to find the object:

```
jQuery.inArray("Apple", fruits["title"]); //this returns -1 why?
```

Any ideas how to search two dimensional array?

Comment: What is `fruits` - does that contain the array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a 2D array, this is an array of objects, so this should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i].title); //Log the title of each object.
    if (array[i].title == "Apple") {
        console.log("Found apple!");
    }
}
```

Also, objects are key/val pairs, denoted by `key : val`, not `key = val`. Your array has syntax errors and shouldn't run.

Answer (score 1):

To be pedantic, you have an array of objects, not a 2d array. Also your syntax for the object parameters is incorrect.

You can use `filter()` on the array to find the values:

```
var array = [
    { css: "SS", title: "Apple"}, 
    { css: "SS", title: "Orange"}, 
    { css: "SS", title: "Banana"}
];
var matches = array.filter(function (obj) { return obj.title == "Apple" });
if (matches.length) {
    // Apple was in the array...
}
```

Comment: So, you say I should call obj.title to see what is in that array under value "title", but when I `console.log(obj.title);` it returns undefiened D; (when I do `console.log(obj[0].title);` it returns first item, can I return all rather than one by one) I cant figure out why.. when I `console.log(obj);` it returns as I showed in example data.

Comment: @JavaNoob `for( var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++ ) { console.log( obj[i].title ); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object like this

```
var peoples = [
  { "name": "bob", "dinner": "pizza" },
  { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" },
  { "name": "larry", "dinner": "hummus" }
];
```

Ignore what's below. Use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method!

```
peoples.filter(function (person) { return person.dinner == "sushi" });
  // => [{ "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" }]
```

---

You can search for people who have `"dinner": "sushi"` using a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
peoples.map(function (person) {
  if (person.dinner == "sushi") {
    return person
  } else {
    return null
  }
}); // => [null, { "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" }, null]
```

or a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
peoples.reduce(function (sushiPeople, person) {
  if (person.dinner == "sushi") {
    return sushiPeople.concat(person);
  } else {
    return sushiPeople
  }
}, []); // => [{ "name": "john", "dinner": "sushi" }]
```

I'm sure you are able to generalize this to arbitrary keys and values!

Answer (score 0):

`fruits` probably is a array, `fruits["title"]` therefor doesn't exist.
You might want to transform your data:

```
var fruitTitles = fruits.map(function(f) { return f.title; });
jQuery.inArray("Apple", fruitTitles);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery docs:
jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )

I've never used this method, but a quick guess:
var hasIt = jQuery.inArray({css:"SS",title:"Apple"}, myArray);

Comment: That wouldn't work for the same reason that `{css:"SS",title:"Apple"}!={css:"SS",title:"Apple"}` evaluates as `true` - you create a new object in your first parameter to `.inArray()` and the array doesn't contain _that_ object, it just contains a similar object that has properties with the same values.

Answer (score 0):

As [the `$.inArray()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inArray/) explains, the first argument to the function is the value to search for. Your array does not have any elements that are equal to the *string* `"Apple"` that you have supplied in the first argument because none of your array elements are strings (they're all objects).

The second argument to `$.inArray()` is supposed to be the array itself, but (assuming `fruits` is the array you show) `fruits["title"]` is undefined because your array has no property called `"title"`, only the objects in the array have that property.

Try this instead:

```
var index = $.inArray("Apple", $.map(fruits, function(el) { return el.title; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var fruits = [
    { css:"SS", title:"Apple"}, 
    { css:"SS", title:"Orange"}, 
    { css:"SS", title:"Banana"}
];

jQuery.grep(fruits,function(fruit){return fruit.title == 'Apple'});
```